# Define Business Process Type at what level

Tags: dxa, sites-9, dxa2.2, dxa-dotnet

Given this [DXA BluePrint](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/21300/can-we-use-content-porter-export-import-to-transfer-between-publications-in-same) where two websites use the same level 100, **110**, 200 publications.

- 100 Master
- 110 DXA Site Type
- 200 Content
- 400 abc Website
- 400 cde Website

We configured BPT at level 110, but both 400 websites can see it.
That will be a problem?
We don't use the preview option. Can we declare Process Type at level 400?
Screens of BFT definition at 110 DXA Site Type.

[image]

Target Types:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply being able to see the Business Process Type from a given publication ought not to be a problem. It's simply available from the blueprint, but you don't have to use it. You can select the Business Process Type you want to use in the publication properties.

In any case, you may *want* to use the same Business Process Type for abc and cde. You probably will: most systems only need one Business Process Type to serve all needs. How often do you do anything other than "Staging and Live"?

Comment: CMS is shared but each application has it own infrastructure (for content delivery).

Comment: That's quite normal, but no reason to need separate Business Process Types. A BPT is quite abstract, and can easily be used for several content delivery environments.